# Combining feature sets using a MultinomialNB

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

This is a very basic question about feature sets.

Let's say I have a group of people with various features that I want to make recommendations to. They have also written a paragraph of free form text that is highly significant in what I need to recommend to them.

I can understand how to vectorize their sample text but I don't know how then to add features such as nationality, age, sex etc etc.

So I have this:

```
#dbsession = sqlalchemy session

people = dbsession.query(People).filter(People.category!="inactive")
all_text = [(a.all_text, a.category) for a in people ]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5, stop_words='english')
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform([x[0] for x in all_text])
y_train = ([x[1] for x in all_text])
classifier = MultinomialNB()
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)

print("Training score: {0:.1f}%".format(classifier.score(X_train, y_train) * 100))
a  = People.populate_from_db(dbsession,2309601) # this gives me the person I want to categorise
print a

sample_text = a.all_text
t_form = vectorizer.transform([sample_text])
probs = classifier.predict_proba(t_form)
for i,p in enumerate(probs[0]):
    print "# ", classifier.classes_[i] , "%.2f %%" % (p*100)
```

(Yes I know that I shouldn't be using an item of the training set to test with, but I am just getting the code running first before putting real data into it.)

Now if a people object had a attribute such as "nationality", what is the best way to add that to the classifier ?

Comment: These are not good features for multinomial NB, because they're not frequencies. Switch to `LogisticRegression`, and use a `DictVectorizer` for the feature extraction. `TfidfVectorizer` is really only meant for term frequency features.

Comment: thanks @larsmans - I am new to this (if you hadn't guessed) and got my main example from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/document_classification_20newsgroups.html . How would I replace with LogisticRegression / DictVectorizer? Just directly in the code ?

Comment: It's quite a bit more involved than that. Forget what I said, the easiest thing you can do is probably add `sex=male` (or `=female`) and `nationality=WHATEVER` to your documents, then see if naive Bayes picks it up.

Comment: Ok.. I am getting the best results with my dataset using a CountVectorizer with ngrams=(1,3) and the LogisticRegression. This wasn't a serious exercise for me but it made something that was quite a dull job into something interesting while learning new stuff at the same time. Thanks again for the points @larmans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The issue of adding additional fields to your vector.

A) Just create a new X_train_extended that has the same number of dimensions as X_train + 1 for each thing you want to add. Copy the values over and insert what you want in the extra space

B) try to use the [FeatureUnion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html#sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion) from scikit to do that for you.

2) Will your addition make sense? In this case - no. Storing a numeric value of 'age' doesn't make sense for the MulinomialNB model. It might work anyway, but you should be aware that what you are doing is now violating the assumptions of the model you are trying to use.

No one can tell you what model you should use since we don't have your data, but you should understand what your model is and what assumptions it makes. Then you can decide what the best form of these additional features would be to put into your model.

Comment: I can understand that a textual value of age serves no purpose, but what if nationality did indicate some trends ? I am assuming that the text written is English, but I was considering the possibility that certain nationalities might fit different groups than others. Thanks for your response so far.

Comment: This shows you don't understand the model. Its not a textual value of age. If age is an integer, MultinomialNB is then saying "age occurred X times" where X is the age. That just doesn't make sense. It might work, but it doesn't make sense. You can't interpret it. Same applied for nationality.

Comment: Sure age isn't a good thing to count... but after adding ngrams=(1,3) I am seeing relevant characteristics being used to accurately evaluate. If I have some time, I'll try the suggestions you made.